# HoG feature vector confusion

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am new in the machine learning world and currently I am working on Computer Vision project. I am confused about HoG feature vector. In my understanding, the feature vector should contain magnitude and orientation of gradients. The gradient is a vector of partial derivations $v = \{ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \}$. We are supposed to calculate this gradient for every pixel in the image.

My question is: **What gradient do we take?** As I understand it, we are supposed to take gradient and its orientation/magnitude, where the biggest change occurs (in shade / color). But what about image like this?

[image]

If we say the white dot is just one pixel, every direction of magnitude has same "scene change" from white to black, how do we chose gradient then?

Secondly, how are we supposed to take the magnitude of gradient? Lets say we have this image:

[image]

If we take 1st pixel (top left) and look for its gradient, the only scene change stats in the middle of image. Do we say the orientation is 0° and magnitude 50px (let's say it's a 100x100 image)?

Or how do we deal with this?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly simple. Since the computer images are discrete, we use some **approximations to compute gradients**. The method to compute the gradients in discrete computer images is called **finite differences**. Usually, we take the *forward* finite difference<sup>1</sup>, meaning the gradient $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ in a pixel at coordinates [a,b] is computed as:
$$\frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial x} = F(a+1,b)-F(a,b).$$
Analogously, 
$$\frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial y} = F(a,b+1)-F(a,b).$$

So you simply compute the difference between intensities in the neighboring two pixels. You repeat this for **every pixel** in the image (except for the right and bottom edge, where no more neighboring pixels are; here we define the gradient to be zero), so the output feature map has the same size as the original image.

To answer your two examples:

1. In the first picture, the gradient will be zero everywhere except for the pixel above the dot (there it will be $[0,1]$), pixel left to the dot ($[1,0]$), and the dot itself ($[-1,-1]$).
2. In the second picture, the gradient will be zero everywhere except for the rightmost black pixels (gradient will be $[1,0]$).

---

<sup>1</sup> Other variants are backward differences and central differences.

Comment: Thanks for answer , why onle a+1 and b+1? why not also a - 1 and b- 1? Also now i realized i am not sure what function F(a,b) do..

Comment: F(a,b) is the pixel value at coordinate (a,b). If you used a-1 and b-1 instead, it would be the backward differences. Does not matter so much, really.

Comment: if F(a,b) is just value of pixel at [a][b] , how can we derivate this function w/e knowing its  prescription?

Comment: But you know its value at every pixel in the image. And the finite differences method tells you how to compute its approximate gradient. The "real" gradient is not defined because the function For is piecewise constant: its derivative is 0 at constant regions (pixel interior) and undefined at the steps (boundary between pixels)

Comment: ah yes, the only question left , when i have gradient A = (F derived x , F derived y ) , is there any math proof that  tan^-1 ( F'x / F'y ) gives the orientaton of gradient?

Comment: That is given by simple trigonometry. Imagine a right triangle with $\Delta x = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ representing one side and $\Delta y =\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ another, with the right angle between them. Then the tangent of an angle $\alpha$ is defined as $\tan \alpha = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$. So, $\alpha = \tan^{-1} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$

Comment: I understand why tan ^-1 gives us the direction in angles, yes simple trigonometry. I meant more of logicali or intuitive. When i calculate Fx = F(a + 1 , b ) - F(a,b ) and Fx = F( a , b + 1 ) -  F(a,b); i get two values  however why can i represent those values as sides in triangle and calculate  the tan^-1? I understand why the formula works,  i do not see why i CAN use that and it would give me wanted answer.

Comment: Because these values represent how fast the image function changes if you move in these directions. So if you know how fast it changes horizontally and vertically, you can obviously infer the angle of the steepest increase ($\alpha$)...

Comment: i see, its more intuitive now, Thanks for help and effort